# How to show graph in day view only in flot chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am trying to set graph in day view only. But this plugin set into week or month view according to the date range. 
I searched a lot on google and read doc and not able to get solution.
I want to show all graph in day view.

**Options**

```
var options = {
        xaxis: {
            mode: "time",
            tickLength: 5,
            timeformat: "%d %b",
            minTickSize : [1, "day"],
        },
        points : {
          show : true
        },
        lines : {
          show : true
        }
    };
```

So please tell me how can I do this.

[Plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/2kKDEuafV2WbjQXHTneE?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. 
Use `tickSize : [1, "day"]` in the option and get graph in day view.

```
var options = {
    xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        tickLength: 5,
        timeformat: "%d %b",
        minTickSize : [1, "day"],
        tickSize : [1, "day"],

    },
    points : {
      show : true
    },
    lines : {
      show : true
    }
};
```

Update Plunker [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/2kKDEuafV2WbjQXHTneE?p=preview)